# Why is fflush() needed between input and output operations for file stream created by fopen()?

Tags: c, linux, c99

Here is a quote from [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/fopen.htm) (also specified in C99 standard)

> When you open a file for update, you can perform both input and output
>   operations on the resulting stream. However, an output operation
>   cannot be directly followed by an input operation without an
>   intervening fflush subroutine call or a file positioning operation
>   (fseek, fseeko, fseeko64, fsetpos, fsetpos64 or rewind subroutine).
>   Also, an input operation cannot be directly followed by an output
>   operation without an intervening flush or file positioning operation,
>   unless the input operation encounters the end of the file.

Why this is necessary?

Comment: [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.

Comment: Note that the above does not recommend `fflush` when switching from reading to writing (contrary to the IBM description). Even though MSVC implements input buffer flushing, which is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

The operations are likely buffered to avoid writing every single byte individually to the disk. Before starting to read we must assure that all previous writes are actually stored on disk.

Also, a seek is likely needed anyway to locate the thing you want to read. So not a problem in practice.

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible to write the standard stream functions in such a way as to allow input and output operations to be freely mixed. The C Standard does not impose such a constraint on the library authors for two main reasons:

- restricting the direction change to certain operations allows for some optimisations, reducing the number of tests for basic input/output functions such as `getc()` and `putc()` which are commonly implemented as simple macros.
- historical implementations took advantage of the above and already had restrictions as to how and when to allow a change of direction.  The C Standard Committee just formalized these restrictions to allow existing code to be conformant.

Newer versions of the C library must lock the streams for all input/output operations, so an extra test for a direction change would have negligible cost but the C Standard is unlikely to remove the restriction.